# Uso de IIFE em ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, escopo-de-variáveis

Em ES5 é considerado uma boa prática utilizar IIFE para forçarmos um escopo local no nosso código. EX:

```
(function(){
  // some code
})();
```

Em ES6 isso ainda é necessário? Uma vez que foi introduzida a keyword `let` para declaração de variáveis?

Obrigado.

Comment: Não é mais necessário se você usar o mecanismo de módulos. O let em si não isola o escopo global.

Answer (score 1):

Ao declarar variáveis com `var` no JS, era preciso criar um novo escopo léxico para não bagunçar a `window` (na maioria dos casos).

```
var abc = 1;

console.log(abc);
// => 1

console.log(window.abc);
// => 1
```

A forma mais simples era criar uma função e chamá-la logo em seguida, já que funções em JavaScript criam um novo escopo léxico. Como você citou, são as IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expressions):

```
(function(){
  var abc = 1;
})();

console.log(abc);
// => Uncaught ReferenceError: abc is not defined
```

Porém no ES6, com a introdução do `let` e `const`, que são declaradores escopados por bloco, isso realmente não é mais preciso. Para outros usos, como criar um namespace, ou escopar variáveis, ainda é preciso criar um novo escopo léxico. Mas não precisa usar o IIFE, no ES6+ é só criar um [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) (`{ ... }`).

```
let x = 1;

{
  let x = 2;
}

console.log(x);
// => 1
```

Como você já deve saber, tudo isso se deve pois:

- `var` é escopado por função
- `let` e `const` são escopados por bloco

Comment: Entendi. Valeu!